# Test custom constraint annotations with JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit5

Implementing a custom constraint annotation, like `@MySize` requires me testing it with unit tests to see if it functions correctly:

```
public class MySizeTest {
   @Test
   public void noMinMax() {
       Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
       // some asserts or so
       dummy.setMyField("");
       dummy.setMyField(null);
       dummy.setMyField("My text");
   }

   @Test
   public void onlyMin() {
       // change @MySize to have min: @MySize(min = 1)
       ... how?
       ... then test with some setMyField:
       Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
       // some asserts or so
       dummy.setMyField("");
       dummy.setMyField(null);
       dummy.setMyField("My text");
   }

   @Test
   public void onlyMax() {
       // change @MySize to have max: @MySize(max = 50)
       ...
   }

   @Test
   public void bothMinMax() {
       // change @MySize to have min and max: @MySize(min = 1, max = 50)
       ...
   }

   private class Dummy {
       @MySize()
       String myField;

       public String getMyField() {
           return myField;
       }

       public void setMyField(String myField) {
           this.myField = myField;
       }
    }
}
```

I assume this has to be done with reflection, but I have no idea how.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Are you interested in whether your annotation holds the specified values as expected or is the testing about at the actual constraint validation?

Comment: Testing the usage of @MySize. It can be used in 4 different ways: @MySize(), @MySize(min=<...some int-value...>), @MySize(max=<...some int-value...>), @MySize(min=<...some int-value...>, max=<...some int-value...>). I don't want to make 4 fields in the test class to test it.

Comment: @neblaz could you explain why don't want to make 4 fields? Validator can validate it separately.

Comment: Currently @MySize has 2 attributes (min, max), could be extended to 3 or 4 attributes, would mean 8 or 16 combinations, thus 8 or 16 different test fields hard-coded in a test class. Better to have one annotated field and let the appropriate test methods modify it. Is this a too hard solution to find? I thought using reflection is the way to go, but me never used it.

Comment: @neblaz You really should consider the introduction of separate fields! Does it feel boring, uncreative, maybe a little dumb? Congratulations, now it's proper test code ;-)

Comment: @neblaz Although I don't agree with your aproach I've updated my answer. Take a look at that.

Comment: Here what I found which points into the direction I was thinking of: https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-change-annotation-params  although it has the annotation on the class, and the annotation has only one method (greet()) in the example.

Comment: @neblaz are you asking about custom constraint annotations used to validate your code, such as Jakarta Bean Validation API offers? (see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/7.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints) Or are you asking about an annotation you came up with on your one that is not part of a validation framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicly don't have to use reflection just create a `Validator` instance and use that for validating.

For examaple:

When the annotation is:

```java
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyValidator.class)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String message() default "Invalid value (it must be foo)";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

and the related validator is:

```java
public class MyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyAnnotation, String> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (null == s) return true;
        return "foo".equalsIgnoreCase(s);
    }
}
```

Then the tests sould be like these:

```java
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class MyValidatorTest {

    private Validator validator;

    @BeforeAll
    void init() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }

    private static class TestObject {

        @MyAnnotation
        private String testField;

        TestObject() {
            this(null);
        }

        TestObject(String value) {
            testField = value;
        }

        public String getTestField() {
            return testField;
        }

        public void setTestField(String testField) {
            this.testField = testField;
        }
    }

    @Test
    void shouldValidForNullValue() {
        var obj = new TestObject();
        var violations = validator.validate(obj); // Set<ConstraintViolation<TestObject>>
        Assertions.assertTrue(violations.isEmpty(), String.format("Object should valid, but has %d violations", violations.size()));
    }

    @Test
    void shouldValidForFooValue() {
        var obj = new TestObject("foo");
        var violations = validator.validate(obj); // Set<ConstraintViolation<TestObject>>
        Assertions.assertTrue(violations.isEmpty(), String.format("Object should valid, but has %d violations", violations.size()));
    }

    @Test
    void shouldInvalidForBarValue() {
        var obj = new TestObject("bar");
        var violations = validator.validate(obj); // Set<ConstraintViolation<TestObject>>
        Assertions.assertEquals(1, violations.size());
    }
}
```

### Update (2020.05.21.) - Using attributes and AnnotationFactory

Based on comments I've updated my answer.
If you want to test only the validation logic then just create an `Annotation` instance and call the `isValid` method which is returns `true` or `false`

Hibernate Validator provides `AnnotationFactory.create(...)` method to make annotaion instance.
After that you can create an instance of your custom validator and call `initialize` and `isValid` methods in your test case.

```java
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyHasAttributesValidator.class)
public @interface MyAnnotationHasAttributes {
    String message() default "Invalid value (it must be foo)";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    int attributeOne() default 10;
    int attributeTwo() default 20;

}
```

related validator:

```java
public class MyHasAttributesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyAnnotationHasAttributes, String> {
    private MyAnnotationHasAttributes ann;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MyAnnotationHasAttributes constraintAnnotation) {
        ann = constraintAnnotation;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (null == s) return true;
        return s.length() >= ann.attributeOne() && s.length() < ann.attributeTwo();
    }
}
```

and the modified test (which has failing assertion):

```java
public class HasAttributeValidatorTest {

    private MyAnnotationHasAttributes createAnnotation(Integer one, Integer two) {
        final Map<String, Object> attrs = new HashMap<>();
        if (null != one) {
            attrs.put("attributeOne", one);
        }
        if (null != two) {
            attrs.put("attributeOne", two);
        }
        var desc = new AnnotationDescriptor.Builder<>(MyAnnotationHasAttributes.class, attrs).build();
        return AnnotationFactory.create(desc);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("provideValues")
    void testValidator(Integer one, Integer two, String input, boolean expected) {
        MyAnnotationHasAttributes ann = createAnnotation(one, two);
        MyHasAttributesValidator validator = new MyHasAttributesValidator();
        validator.initialize(ann);
        var result = validator.isValid(input, null);
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, result, String.format("Validation must be %s but found: %s with params: %d, %d, %s", expected, result, one, two, input));
    }

    private static Stream<Arguments> provideValues() {
        return Stream.of(
                Arguments.of(null, null, null, true),
                Arguments.of(null, 20, "foo", true),
                Arguments.of(null, null, RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(30), false)
        );
    }
}
```

***Limitations of this solution***

*Vendor lock*

In this case your test using Hibernate Validator which is a specific implementation if the Bean Validation standards. Honestly I don't think it's a huge problem, because Hibernate Validator is the refecerence implementation and the most popular bean validation library. But technically it's a vendor lock.

*Cross field validation is unavailable*

This soulution works only in one-field situations. If you have e.g a cross-field validator (e.g. password and confirmPassword matching) this example won't fit.

*Type independent validation needs more work*

Like previously mentioned `@Size` annotation belongs to several different validator implementations based on type (primitives, collections, string, etc.).
Using this solution you always have to chose the certain validator manually and test it.

*Only the `isValid` method can be tested*

In this case you won't be able to test another things just the isValid method. I mean e.g. error message has expected format and parameters or something like this.

In sort, I know creating many different fields with different annotation attributes is boring but I strongly prefer that way because you can test everything you need about your validator.

Comment: Don't think that answers my question. See my comment below my question. I want to test the usage of @MySize.

Comment: It has min and max, just like @Size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and effort, still have to get through it and understand it. Here what I found which points into the direction I was thinking of: https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection-change-annotation-params  although it has the annotation on the class, and the annotation has only one method (greet()) in the example.

Comment: @zforgo
In your @ Override isValid(..)  you are using a return statement of the structure
return ((condition 1) && (condition 2)). The && is fast breaking - meaning that if condition 1 evaluates to false, condition 2 will not be evaluated anymore. In case violations 1 and 2 are not mutually exclusive, you might want to use only a single & when evaluating. That way the resulting ConstraintViolation-Set will contain information to validation errors from both conditions. This becomes even more important if you have more complex conditions and exclude the checks into several function calls.